# Show AlertDialog depending on how AsyncTask.execute() runs in the same code block

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm writing a function which executes Http request (with the help of HttpPost, HttpClient and AsyncTask) and shows AlertDialog if `HttpClient.execute()`(which runs in `AsyncTask.doInBackground()`) takes too much time.

The problem is that I should wait for some time after `AsyncTask.execute()` is called, before showing the message. But if I use `AsyncTask.get()` to prevent my function from finish, nothing can be changed in the UI until AsyncTask is finished.
Here is the code example:

```
{
    HttpClient mHttpClient;
    HttpPost mHttpPostAuth;

    public Boolean openConnection()
    {
        //Checking if HttpClient.execute() is finished within 300 milliseconds
        //howing the message if not
        mScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(!mResponseReceived){
                            try{
                                mWaitingForResposeAlert = mWaitingForResposeBuilder.show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        try{
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, HttpResponse>(){
                @Override
                protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Void... params){
                    try {                       
                        mResponseReceived = false;
                        HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpPostAuth);
                        mResponseReceived = true;
                        return response;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                    }

                    mResponseReceived = true;
                    return null;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse response){
                    try{
                        if (response == null) return;
                        switch (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()){
                            case HttpStatus.SC_OK:{
                                //Reading the response
                                break;
                            }
                            default:{
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                    }
                }
            }.execute().get();

        if(mWaitingForResposeAlert != null) mWaitingForResposeAlert.dismiss();

        return !(sid==null);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to show AlertDialog depending on how `AsyncTask.execute()` runs in the same code block?

Comment: Why not use `publishProgress` and `onProgressUpdate` of `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @AleksG The problem is that if get() was called then onProgressUpdate() will be called only after doInBackground()'s finish.

Comment: that's not true.  onProgressUpdate will be called every time you call publishProgress from your doInBackground

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to show AlertDialog depending on how
>   AsyncTask.execute() runs in the same code block?

You can show AlertDialog / ProgressDialog

- In `onPreExecute()` method that is called before AsyncTask start
  working
- Or call `publicProgress()` in `doInBackground()` method It will
  invoke `onProgressUpdate()` method automatically and in this method you
  can also show AlertDialog / ProgressDialog

**Example:**

```
@Override
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Void... unused) {
   ...
   publishProgress(); // it invokes onProgressUpdate() method
   ...
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {
   // here show Dialog
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the problem is that openConnection() from which AsyncTask is called should return a value depending on data from HttpPost.execute() so I need to call AsyncTask.get() to prevent my function from finishing too early. But after calling get() even onProgressUpdate() can’t do anything with the UI thread until AsyncTask execution is finished.

Comment: @Userr you are complicate things where you don't have so what you want to achieve?simply show alertdialog when client.execute() takes much more time than 300 ms?

Comment: I just need a function which can make http request with httpclient, return boolean value depending on it's success, and show message if httpclient.execute() takes more than 300 ms.

Comment: so why you are doing it so "hard"? so normaly doInBackground will return boolean value depends on client.execute() before you call client.execute() create some timer with thread that will control time of executing request, in run() method of timer put boolean that while (!timeout) {count++; Thread.sleep(1);} if count reach 300 value, change boolean to true and show dialog.